# Understanding Haskell (<-) syntactic sugar

Tags: haskell, monads, do-notation

I'm trying to parse a CSV file using Cassava. I want a function that returns `Nothing` if parse was unsuccessful and `Just (V.Vector (String, String, String))` otherwise.

I'm using the code below:

```
  {-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
module Lib
    ( someFunc
    ) where

import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as BL
import Data.Csv
import qualified Data.Vector as V

type Dataset = (String, String, String)
someFunc :: Maybe (V.Vector Dataset)
someFunc = do
    csvData <- BL.readFile "TAEE3.SA.csv"
    case decode HasHeader csvData :: Either String (V.Vector (String, String, String)) of
      Left a -> Nothing
      Right v -> Just v
```

The error is:

```
  • Couldn't match type ‘IO’ with ‘Maybe’
      Expected type: Maybe BL.ByteString
        Actual type: IO BL.ByteString
    • In a stmt of a 'do' block: csvData <- BL.readFile "TAEE3.SA.csv"
      In the expression:
        do csvData <- BL.readFile "TAEE3.SA.csv"
           case  decode HasHeader csvData ::
                   Either String (V.Vector (String, String, String))
           of
             Left a -> Nothing
             Right v -> Just v
      In an equation for ‘someFunc’:
          someFunc
            = do csvData <- BL.readFile "TAEE3.SA.csv"
                 case  decode HasHeader csvData ::
                         Either String (V.Vector (String, String, String))
                 of
                   Left a -> Nothing
                   Right v -> Just v
   |
14 |     csvData <- BL.readFile "TAEE3.SA.csv"
   |                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

It's like the `<-` function is not working at all. Isn't it supposed to return an `a` in `IO a` monad?

Comment: that doesn't work because you're trying to do IO (readFile) inside a Maybe monad. also `<-` is not a function, it's merely syntactic sugar for `>>=`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While `<-` does give you the `a` in `IO a`, it doesn't do it by taking it out of the IO monad. In general, it's impossible to take a value out of monads. What it actually does is put the rest of the `do` block in the monad too. To account for this, you need to make your function return its result in `IO`, and then add a `return` to wrap your final `Maybe` back in `IO`:

```
  {-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
module Lib
    ( someFunc
    ) where

import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as BL
import Data.Csv
import qualified Data.Vector as V

type Dataset = (String, String, String)
someFunc :: IO (Maybe (V.Vector Dataset))
someFunc = do
    csvData <- BL.readFile "TAEE3.SA.csv"
    return $ case decode HasHeader csvData :: Either String (V.Vector (String, String, String)) of
      Left a -> Nothing
      Right v -> Just v
```

Comment: What do you mean it's impossible to take a value of a monad?

Comment: @testin3r `Maybe` is a monad. If I give you `Nothing` and tell you to take the value out of it, what value would that be?